# Show that isotropic function S(A) and A have same eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, rotations, diagonalization, invariant-theory

Given $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a  positive definite, symmetric second order tensor and
$\boldsymbol{Q}\boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{A})\boldsymbol{Q}^T = \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{QAQ}^T)$ $\forall   \boldsymbol{Q}$ which are orthogonal, then each eigenvector of $\boldsymbol{A}$ is also an eigenvector of $\boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{A})$.

My specific question: If the orthogonal tensor $\boldsymbol{Q_1}$ diagonalizes $\boldsymbol{A}$, then  $\boldsymbol{Q_1}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{Q_1}^T = \boldsymbol{D}$, so that

$\boldsymbol{Q_1}\boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{A})\boldsymbol{Q_1}^T = \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{D})$.

Can I conclude from this that $\boldsymbol{Q_1}$ diagonalizes $\boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{A})$  and hence the eigenvectors are the same ?

**EDIT 1**: I attach an image showing the standard proof. I understand it, but I would like to know if mine is wrong.[image]
**EDIT 2**: Changed my symbols to match that of the stated lemma.

Comment: If $g$ transform diagonal matrix to diagonal matrix

Comment: @Hamou  Isnt S(D) diagonal  by definition of a matrix function ?